# Security has requested to process its policy settings again. Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy, deployment, windows-event-log

I am receiving the following error with a yellow exclamation mark in the group policy results wizard when deploying software using a GPO.

> Security has requested to process its policy settings again. This can
>   be due to non-critical errors occurring during the previous processing
>   of policy.
>
> Additional information may have been logged. Review the Policy Events
>   tab in the console or the application event log for events between
>   8/09/2013 3:24:54 p.m. and 8/09/2013 3:25:21 p.m..

It only occurs on one particular client, an identical computer with the same policy settings does not throw the same error.  I have checked the event viewer on the local machine and the only error in the above time frame is one saying:

> Completed Security Extension Processing in 26739 milliseconds.

Does anyone have any idea whats causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.  To find the error I had to dive into the winlogon log file.   The problem was my policy was enabling the built-in administrator account but the password was empty and failed the password complexity requirements.  I had to also add the administrator account with a password as another policy.  Hope this helps someone else.